# pass xml to php function

Tags: php, xml

I am thinking of passing a XML string to a function then I'll return the parent node together with its value.

Say for an example:

```
$xml = "<Student><Name>Jee Pee</Name><Age>16</Age></Student>";
runXmltoStr($xml);

function runXmltoStr($xml)
{
// This is where I can't figure out where to start
// In my mind, I do have this output
//
// Student
// Name: Jee Pee
// Age: 16
}
```

Comment: Start by having a read of the PHP XML Parser: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use an XML parser, such as [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/SimpleXML):

```
$xml_node = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$xml_node->Name; // Jee Pee
$xml_node->Age; // 16
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Cooper. I tried to `print_r($xml_node);` but I don't see the Student on the key of an array. My purpose of looking for it is, I like to include it on my output.

Comment: @Dee:  Like I posted, you can access the nodes like you would access an object's properties, like so: `$simplexml_node->SubnodeName`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

To load the string into an XML element and then use SimpleXML: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php to get the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could give a look to the [DOM manipulation features of PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) that can do all that kind of stuff for you.

DOM is not the fastest way of parsing XML but it's reliable and easy to implement over complex XML data structures.